# Derbyjs: access session in app routes or x-bind function

Tags: node.js, express, derbyjs

1. derby new TestDerby
2. Uncomment server/index.js
3. add `console.log(model.get(),model.session)` to app/index.js - this.start
4. model.session is undefined

   (had a quick look at racer/lib/session/session.Store.js)

or derby recommend to use `model.set('_session-item-key',value)` instead of session?

Comment: it seems that the model.session only exist at server, so if I want to access session at a client route, what should I do instead of using session.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to session via model.session. Write a custom middleware to hook into the creation of your expressApp: `model = req.getModel(); model.set('_whatever', model.session.whatever);` [Example custom middleware](https://github.com/lefnire/habitrpg/blob/master/src/server/index.coffee#L33), [example model.session](https://github.com/lefnire/habitrpg/blob/master/src/app/index.coffee#L24)